# laravel 4: order object in template

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to order the tests for each user in descending order of created_at. I tried it in the template but I didn't succeed. These are my tables:

```
 | users      |   | courses    |    | tests      |
 | ---------- |   |------------|    |------------|
 | id         |   | id         |    | id         |
 | name       |   | name       |    | name       |
 | created_at |   | created_at |    | created_at |
                  | user_id    |    | course_id  |
```

A user has many courses and a course has many tests. I'll like to order all the tests in descending order of created_at.

I tried this in my template:

```
@foreach(User::find($user->id)->courses as $course)
        @foreach(Course::find($course->id)->tests as $test)
            <p>Name: {{$test->name}}</p>
            <p>Date: {{$test->created_at}}</p>
        @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Edit: There are my models

User.php

```
   public function courses()
   {
    return $this->hasMany('Course');
   }
```

Course.php

```
   public function user()
    {
    return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }

   public function test()
    {
    return $this->hasMany('Test');
    }
```

Test.php

```
   public function courses()
    {
    return $this->belongsTo('Course');
    }
```

Comment: You just want to try in template not any other place? Eg. Order in your Model

Comment: If the solution was implemented in the Controllers it's not a problem.

Comment: You just want to order in template?

Comment: I want to display tests in order in the template.

Comment: Can you describe your Models?

Comment: I'm using these three models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this, do it in your `Controller`:

```
$users = User::with(array('courses.tests' => function($query) {
    $query->orderBy('tests.created_at', 'desc');
}))->find($user->id);
```

Then load the view and pass the `$user` object like this:

```
return View::make('your_view_name')->withuser($user);
```

Then in your `view` try something like this:

```
@foreach($user->courses->tests as $test)
        <p>Name: {{ $test->name }}</p>
        <p>Date: {{ $test->created_at }}</p>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply add the orderBy command to your query, like:

```
@foreach($user->courses as $course)
    @foreach($course->tests()->orderBy('created_at', DESC)->get() as $test)
        <p>Name: {{$test->name}}</p>
        <p>Date: {{$test->created_at}}</p>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Look that it's not a good practice to make queries in the views, so I changed your query in some variables you should be setting in your controller. 
Also change test() method to tests(), because it's a one-to-many relation, and it's clearer to have plurals as method name.

Comment: Also consider using hasManyThrough as a relation:
http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#has-many-through

The case described in the Laravel documentation is exactly the same as yours, and it would be much more elegant and you'd worry much less about queries :)